# Custom Validation in Java

Tags: java, spring-boot, валидация

Речь пойдет об обычной валидации связанных полей.
Например, есть класс

```
Person
    String firstName;
    String lastName;
    Int age
и т.д.
```

Предположим, мне нужна валидационная логика, где в POST-запросе если пользователь вводит lastName, то обязательно нужно ввести `firstName`.
`.

**Аннотация:**

```
@Target({TYPE})
@Retention(RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotNullIfAnFieldHasValueValidator.class)
@Documented
@Inheritance
public @interface NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue {

    String message() default "Not null if another field has value";
    Class<?>[] groups() default {};
    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
String first();
String second();
```

**Реализация:**

```
public class NotNullIfAnFieldHasValueValidator implements ConstraintValidator<NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue, Object> {

    private String firstFieldName;
    private String secondFieldName;

@Override
public void initialize(NotNullIfAnotherFieldHasValue
                               constraintAnnotation) {
    firstFieldName = constraintAnnotation.first();
    secondFieldName = constraintAnnotation.second();
}


public boolean isValid(Object value, final
    ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
//        return !secondObj.equals("") && firstObj.equals("”");
               final String firstObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, firstFieldName);
                final String secondObj = BeanUtils.getProperty(value, secondFieldName);
                if (secondObj != null & firstObj.equals("")) {
                    return false;
                }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

Аннотацию можно вешать на любой класс, указывая два зависмых филда, думаю тут всё понятно.

Хочу пойти дальше и создаю интерфейс

```
public interface FirstSecondFieldInterface {
    String getFirstField();
    String getSecondField();

}

public class PersonEntity implements FirstSecondFieldInterface
…………
@Override
public String getFirstField() {
    return firstName;
}

@Override
public String getSecondField() {
    return lastName;
}
```

Теперь хочется сделать следующую логику:

1. Если класс имплеметит интерфейс, то достать филды из override методов интерфейса и уже сравнивать по ним
2. Иначе, если класс ничего не implements этот интерфейс, ничего не делать.

Т.е.  теперь в аннотацию ничего не должен указывать, а она сама всё должна проверить и достать филды, которые возвращают методы интерфейса.

Comment: Какой тип валидации используется в спринг?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Если класс имплеметит интерфейс, то достать филды из override методов интерфейса и уже сравнивать по ним

```
public boolean isValid(Object value, final
    ConstraintValidatorContext context) {
               if (!(value instanceof FirstSecondFieldInterface)) {
                   return true;
               }
               FirstSecondFieldInterface obj = (FirstSecondFieldInterface)value;  
               final String firstObj = obj.getFirstField();
                final String secondObj = obj.getSecondField();
                if (secondObj != null & firstObj.equals("")) {
                    return false;
                }

            return true;
        }
    }
```

---

На самом деле, если ты хочешь помечать интерфейсом, то тебе и аннотация не нужна. Просто сделай custom validator, который умеет проверять классы, помеченные интерфейсом, см. пример в доках https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/5.3.x/reference/html/core.html#validator